# What is the unit of duration in cucumber report json file?

Tags: cucumber, cucumber-java

Can anyone tell me what is the unit of duration, found inside step.result captured inside cucumber reporting json? Is it millisecond, microsecond, nanosecond or anything else?

Comment: Its in nanosecond, I cannot find any documentation related to it anyway

Comment: https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/1796209e02e4f61ab9c6504bfb800aaaaf411e25/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/plugin/JsonFormatter.java#L327

Answer (score 4):

It's nanos. Divide to **1'000'000'000** to get seconds value.

```
1       000     000     000

second  millis  micros  nanos
```

[Source](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-jvm/blob/1796209e02e4f61ab9c6504bfb800aaaaf411e25/core/src/main/java/io/cucumber/core/plugin/JsonFormatter.java#L327)

Answer (score -1):

For me at least its Microseconds

I.e.

```
"Duration": 8303000000
```

Means 8.303 Seconds